# Update Textbox from another class

Tags: c#

I need to write into a textbox on Form1 class from another class, but can't get it to work.

I'll use a very simple example of what I want to acheive.  On Form1 I have a combobox with collection of items 1,2,3,4,5. And also a textbox. Based on what is selected in the combobox, a different message will appear in the text box.  For example if I choose 1 in the combobox, textbox1 will say "1 was selected". if I choose 2 in the combobox textbox1 will say "2 was selected", etc.

I'm using a switch statement for this, but I dont want the switch statement to be in Form1.cs but instead in Class1.cs  But i can't get the text into the textbox unless I have the switch statement in Form1.cs. But I really want the switch statement to be in Class1.cs.  I've tried making both my textbox and combobox public but it didn't make a difference.

This is what I have in Form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ComboBox1Text
    {
        get { return comboBox1.Text; }
    }

    public string TextBox1Text
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.FunctionSelect();
    }
}
```

And this is the other class Class1.cs:

```
class Class1
{
    public void FunctionSelect()
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        string switcher = form1.ComboBox1Text;
        switch (switcher)
        {
            case "1":
                form1.TextBox1Text = "1 was selected";
                break;
            case "2":
                form1.TextBox1Text = "2 was selected";
                break;
            case "3":
                form1.TextBox1Text = "3 was selected";
                break;
            case "4":
                form1.TextBox1Text = "4 was selected";
                break;
            case "5":
                form1.TextBox1Text = "5 was selected";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I select something in the combobox nothing happens in the text box.  But if I move my switch statement in FunctionSelect() from Class1.cs to Form1.cs it works exactly as I expected.  But really I need FunctionSelect() to be in Class1.cs - Not in Form1.cs.  I believe the problem is due to creating a new instance for Form1 in Class1.cs (Form1 form1 = new Form1()), which means I'm not actually writing to the Form1 displayed on the screen.  But I can't work out how to write to the textbox on Form1.cs from Class1.cs.

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple, but can't work it out, and can't find a post that answers exactly as I need.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicion is well funded your problem is exactly that you are making a new form1, there is a number of ways on how to achieve what you are trying to do, one would be to pass the form as a parameter to your other class, another could be using event pattern, and you can find many more.

I will explain how to do the first one:

First you need to update your Class1 to have a constructor that take a Form1 class as a parameter and you save the reference to that class inside the class1. Then you can use that instance to work on your Form1 class. See example above.

NOTE: As a rule of thumb you should use delegates, in this particular case it works fine without one, but you should check whether invoke is required or not when modifying values on the UI thread. Another thing that can be improved there is no need to instanciate many class1, you could have a Class one instansiation and use that class forever, and not going making several classes.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ComboBox1Text
    {
        get { return comboBox1.Text; }
    }

    public string TextBox1Text
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1(this);
        class1.FunctionSelect();
    }
}



public class Class1
{
    private Form1 _instance;

    public Class1(Form1 instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }

    public void FunctionSelect()
    {
        string switcher = _instance.ComboBox1Text;
        switch (switcher)
        {
            case "1":
                _instance.TextBox1Text = "1 was selected";
                break;
            case "2":
                _instance.TextBox1Text = "2 was selected";
                break;
            case "3":
                _instance.TextBox1Text = "3 was selected";
                break;
            case "4":
                _instance.TextBox1Text = "4 was selected";
                break;
            case "5":
                _instance.TextBox1Text = "5 was selected";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form class doesn't change:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     public Form1()
     {
          InitializeComponent();
     }

     public string ComboBox1Text
     {
          get { return comboBox1.Text; }
     }

    public string TextBox1Text
    {
         get { return textBox1.Text; }
         set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          Class1 class1 = new Class1();
          class1.FunctionSelect();
    }
```

And this is the second class

```
class Class1
{
public void FunctionSelect()
{
    Form1 form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms[0];

    string switcher = form1.ComboBox1Text;
    switch (switcher)
    {
        case "1":
            form1.TextBox1Text = "1 was selected";
            break;
        case "2":
            form1.TextBox1Text = "2 was selected";
            break;
        case "3":
            form1.TextBox1Text = "3 was selected";
            break;
        case "4":
            form1.TextBox1Text = "4 was selected";
            break;
        case "5":
            form1.TextBox1Text = "5 was selected";
            break;
      }
    }
 }
```

Application.OpenForms[index] is readonly "FormCollection" how contains all opened forms and can be indexed by int or by string (form name), but it has to be casted in your form type because it type is "Form" (base class of your form)

Example:

```
 MyForm fm=(MyFormType)Application.OpenForm["MyFormName"]; // or 0 for example
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netframework-4.8